# How to generate Image of HTML interpreted code in Webbrowser using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate an Image of following type of code using **Javascript** or **Jquery**.

```
<html>
    <div id="one">
       <h1>sometext</h1>
       <img src=”path/abc.jpg”>
       <video> </video>
       <p>Sometext</p>
    </div
    <div id="two">
       <h1>sometext</h1>
       <img src=”path/abc.jpg”>
       <video> </video>
       <p>Sometext</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

In short I want to create an image (jpg/png) of output generated by above code in web browser using **Javascript** or **Jquery**.

And what to do if I want to generate an image of partial html page like for particular .....

Comment: I believe you have to use a server side language for this, like php

Comment: Thanks Sajith Nair, Can you please share php code for that with me as I am new to php?

Comment: @Stan, look at PhantomJS, specifically this: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html